# shutting down a php process using pcntl_signal when running a thread

Tags: php, pthreads, pcntl, sigterm

When running a thread, the function registered with `pcntl_signal`, never gets fired.

```
<?php
declare(ticks = 1);

class Task extends Thread {
    public function run () {
        while (1) sleep(1); // run forever
    }
}

function shutdown () { // never runs :(
    echo "Good bye!\n"; exit;
}

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'shutdown');

$task = new Task;
$task->start();
```

Then, in the terminal:

```
# kill -TERM 123
```

Works fine when there is not a thread:

```
<?php
declare(ticks = 1);

class Task {
    public function run () {
        while (1) sleep(1); // run forever
    }
}

function shutdown () {
    echo "Good bye!\n"; exit;
}

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'shutdown');

$task = new Task;
$task->run();
```

How can I execute some code when I send SIGTERM when running a thread?
I'm using: php-5.6.7, pthreads-2.0.10, debian-7

Comment: What is `Thread` class ? Is it part of `pthreads` or is it a homemade class ? Strange that extending from Threads breaks it... Are you sure your code actually runs ? Maybe it crashes at `Task`'s definition, whithout executing your last 3 lines... ? Did you have a look to your `php_error.log` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread is oblivious to the registered signal while trying to join the thread. This is essentially what happens after `$task->start()`.

You have to do two things:

1. Find a way to let your main thread react to the signal.
2. Stop the thread from executing, so it won't block [`exit`](http://php.net/exit).

As for 1, you could put your main thread in an endless [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep) loop. While PHP is [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep)ing, it still can react to signals.

And 2, you could [`kill`](http://php.net/thread.kill) the thread in your `shutdown` function.

### In Code

After `$task->start()`:

```
for (;;) {
    sleep(PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

Changed `shutdown` function:

```
function shutdown ()
{
    echo "Good bye!\n";
    $GLOBALS['task']->kill();
    exit;
}
```

Note: Don't use [`kill`](http://php.net/thread.kill) in the real world. Find a method to let the thread gracefully terminate on its own.

### Apropos Signals

I won't recommend using `declare(ticks = 1)`, it's bad for performance. Try using [pcntl_signal_dispatch()](http://php.net/pcntl_signal_dispatch) instead, after [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep) for example.